# JBoss AS not starting / not accessible

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

If i try to start the standalone version of my JBoss AS, i get the following log:

```
D:\Programme\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone>standalone
Calling "D:\Programme\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: D:\Programme\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: D:\Programme\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
onfig=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
23:32:55,389 INFORMATION [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
23:32:58,023 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
23:32:58,298 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" sta
rting
```

I can't access the server at

```
http://localhost:8080
```

It looks like the server is not starting?
I already tried restart windows.

Comment: Yes server is not running. You will get below in server.log after successful startup.

[org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 4315ms

Comment: It says the server is "starting"; once your log says "started" then you would be able to access the server at that address.
If it does not start and gives some error. post the log and somebody would definitely help you out.